# Is there a form of radiation that is blocked by magnetic fields but not by matter?

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

Does there exist a form of radiation which is blocked only by magnetic fields but not by matter. For example, alpha particles are blocked by both magnetic fields (they are deflected by the field) and matter (they are stopped by the matter). Is there a form of radiation where the radiation is blocked by the magnetic field but not by matter?

Comment: Why have you accepted an answer that tells you what radiation *is not* blocked by magnetic fields but is blocked by matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does there exist a form of radiation which is blocked only by magnetic fields but not by matter.

No there is not. All forms of charged radiation are deflected by magnetic fields. They also interact with matter and hence are blocked by matter (depending on the energy of the radiation and characteristics of the matter, like thickness and density).

Speaking from a classical physics perspective and I’m not going to involve more complicated forms of radiation such as neutrons, neutrinos etc since they have no charge.

Basically, there are three forms of radiation. Alpha, beta and gamma.

Alpha particles as you stated can be deflected by magnetic fields due to the Lorentz force. This is equally true for beta radiation (electrons). In fact, all charged particles are deflected by magnetic fields (provided they are in motion).

The other form of radiation, gamma rays which are photons, do not interact this way with magnetic fields since they have no charge (as do other particles) and hence are not deflected.

I would not use the term “block” but instead use “deflect”. And all these forms of radiation are blocked by matter to some degree (gamma rays being the least affected by matter).

So to answer your question, the form of radiation not “blocked” by magnetic fields are gamma rays. But they are blocked by matter as well (provided the matter is dense enough).

Comment: I think your list of radiation is outdated. Even if one could not be concerned about neutrinos, I think that at least neutrons should be added to the list. Not to say about all kinds of cosmic rays. Furthermore, the energy of the radiation and the magnetic field intensity are also important factors to take into account.

Comment: The questions asks for a type of radiation that *is* blocked by magnetic fields but not by matter.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends to some extent on how strong is the magnetic field and how dense is the matter - but in principle, the answer is no.

To have their trajectories altered by a magnetic field, the particles need to be charged. But charged particles interact strongly with matter.

Obviously you could design specific situations with a very strong magnetic field and thin matter, where say a stream of beta particles (electrons) could be deflected by the magnetic field but would easily traverse through the matter.